SEO: How to handle closed account subdomains in a multi-tenant SaaS app?
We have a multi-tenant SaaS app where each customer gets their own subdomain. Currently, when a customer closes their account their login page is still visible on their subdomain - https://customer1.example.com/login.
We want to redirect all those closed account pages to a single "Account closed" page on a special subdomain - for example: https://accounts.example.com/account-closed.
Our subdomain routing is done with a simple wildcard in Route 53 which points to our CloudFront-hosted web app. So: *.example.com is mapped to webapp.example.com. This means we can't easily do server side 301 redirects, at least not without rethinking our entire serving architecture. It also means we can only tell that an account is disabled in the client side JavaScript.
We have a number of existing closed accounts, where their login page may still have links pointing to them from various places.
What would be the best practices here in terms of SEO? We were planning on just doing a client side redirect in JS after we fetch the customer details (which is the first thing the web app does) and we see it's a disabled account.
I know server side 301 is always preferred, but any major issues with our proposed approach? Any SEO implications?
